# Adding constructor to the class ordered_dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this task to construct a new ordered dictionary object reading from a file, In the file, lines are key delimiter value but i have no idea how to read from a file i have this code below but dont know how to move on with it. can anyone give me an idea?

```
def __init__(self, filename, delimiter):
    self._root = None
```

Answer (score 0):

To read from a file use `open(filename, 'r')`.

Specifically, in your case i would use a context manager:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    f.read()
```

if you're new to python, you should really check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/).

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) is documentation relating to your specific question